# scaffolding views from controllers (model already exists)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, scaffolding

I have a c# MVC 4 Web app with code first models and controllers which i done manually.

Is there a quick way of scaffolding views from the controllers? or do i need to code it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have controller with action that returns data as list or other type then do the following.

```
1. right click on the action name
2. click on Add view
3. check mark on "Create a strongly typed view"
4. select your "Model class" from drop down
5. select list/as you need from "scaffold template" dropdown
6. click on add button
```

This will generate a view with all the attributes from your selected model

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2013, you can right-click on the view in this line`return View();` of your controller and their is a add view option. I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: adding a view only adds the @model IEnumerable<JobTracker.Models.Category> line at the top of the code, i was hoping to save time and have the  for loop through the model and its attributes already generated

Comment: well have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208471/automatically-detect-all-models-to-scaffold?rq=1) post? this guy problem seems to be the same

Comment: i used the guide within it there to generate the views and  discarded the controllers in turn for modifying my own controllers. Thank you!